# How to block iframe in Perl?

Tags: perl, iframe, block

I need to block iframe in perl, I'm search PHP script:

php script: header("X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY");

it works fine

but I need it in Perl

Please anyone help me

Thank you

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset

Comment: print "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY\n\n"; It Works! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work but make sure you are printing it before you send the content-type,  like so:

```
 print "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY\n";
 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```

Comment: Re "make sure you are printing it before you send the content-type", huh? I seriously doubt that's necessary, and it's against the recommended practices of HTTP. It probably simply needs to be found before the end of the header (i.e. before the first blank line)

Comment: @ikegami - The example I have given works and you are correct that my explanation should have been "make sure it's sent before the end of the header. In the example given the end of the header is designated by the two newlines after the content-type.